# How to drop the index column while writing the DataFrame in a .csv file in Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame contains two columns named 'a','b'. 
Now when I created a csv file of this DataFrame:

> df.to_csv('myData.csv')

And when I opened this in an excel file, there is an extra column with indices that appears alongside the columns 'a' and 'b', but I don't want that. I only want columns 'a' and 'b' to appear in the excel sheet.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try,

```
 df.to_csv('myData.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Extremely simple and elegant solution to someone who is no longer ignorant about it.  Works like a charm.  Using it in combination with xlsxwriter ```df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)```